# How can I change the value of one cell conditioned to different values of another?

Tags: r, loops

I created a new column called performance, and I need to change the values of each cell conditioned to the value of another column.

First I created the column like this

```
biperf$performance <- 0
```

So the data frame looks like this:

```
ID   performance
1        0
1        0
1        0
1        0
2        0
2        0
2        0 
2        0  
3        0
3        0
3        0
3        0
15       0
15       0
15       0
15       0 
16       0
16       0
16       0
16       0
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
ID   performance
1        good
1        good
1        good
1        good
2        0
2        0
2        0 
2        0  
3        0
3        0
3        0
3        0
15       good
15       good
15       good
15       good 
16       good
16       good
16       good
16       good
```

Then I tried this and it worked, but I have 200 different IDs, with 20 observations each instead of the 4 I put here as an example.

```
biperf$performance[biperf$ID == "1"] <- "good"
biperf$performance[biperf$ID == "15"] <- "good"
biperf$performance[biperf$ID == "16"] <- "good"
```

So I tried these methods:

```
perf$performance <- ifelse(perf$ID %in% c('1', '15','16'), "good", perf$performance)
```

This changed all the cells under performance. So I tried a loop but it gave me an error and I couldn't make it work.

```
if(biperf$ID %in% c('1','15','16')){
  biperf$performance = "good"
}
```

I looked for this in the forum, but I didn't find any that includes many values in the conditioning cells. ID is a factor. Besides "good" I need also other values for other IDs.

Thank you!

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that. I edited it already :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're `ifelse` is a good approach, you just need to keep numeric and character values straight:

```
# create example dataframe
biperf <- data.frame(ID = rep(c(1,2,3,15,16), each=4))

# do your ifelse (notice no quotes around 1/15/16, yes quotes around "0" and "good"
beperf$performance <- ifelse(biperf$ID %in% c(1, 15, 16), "good", "0")
```

Comment: This is great and it worked, but if I want to add other values like "bad" or "awful" I cannot use it because it turns the rest into 0s. I have four values I would like to distribute among the 200 IDs. Sorry if I wasn't clear with my example/question.

Comment: If you want to do other criteria after the initial step above, this will for example replace all of the zeros for ID=3 or ID=4 with "great":  `beperf[beper$ID %in% c(3,4), "performance"] <- "great"`